# Как сделать валидацию формы с всплывающим уведомлением?

Tags: javascript, валидация, формы, уведомления

Как сделать валидацию для полей?

Допустим если в поле `имя` введено 2 символа, то всплывает такое оповещение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```js
function validateForm() {
  $('.call-form button[type="submit"').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#formNameCall");
    var email = $("#formEmailCall");
    var phone = $("#formPhoneCall");
    var nameVal = $("#formNameCall").val();
    var emailVal = $("#formEmailCall").val();
    var phoneVal = $("#formPhoneCall").val();

    if (nameVal.length > 2 && emailVal.length > 5 && phoneVal.length > 5) {
      var $data;
      $data = $(this).parent('form').serialize();
      $(".modal").addClass('modal--visible');
      $.ajax({
        url: 'test.ru',
        type: 'post',
        data: $data
      });
    }
    if (nameVal.length < 2) {
      name.css({
        'box-shadow': 'inset 0 0 10px red'
      });
    } else {
      name.css({
        'box-shadow': 'none'
      });
    }

    if (emailVal.length < 5) {
      email.css({
        'box-shadow': 'inset 0 0 10px red'
      });
    } else {
      email.css({
        'box-shadow': 'none'
      });
    }

    if (phoneVal.length < 5) {
      phone.css({
        'box-shadow': 'inset 0 0 10px red'
      });
    } else {
      phone.css({
        'box-shadow': 'none'
      });
    }

  });
}
```

```css
.error {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #D9585C;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form id="ltForm1241541" class="call-form" action="https://virilisgk.getcourse.ru/pl/lite/block-public/process-html?id=747751498" method="post" data-open-new-window="0"><input type="hidden" name="formParams[setted_offer_id]">
  <input id="formNameCall" type="text" maxlength="60" placeholder="* Имя" name="formParams[full_name]" value=""><br>
  <input id="formEmailCall" type="text" maxlength="60" placeholder="* Email" name="formParams[email]" value=""><br>
  <input id="formPhoneCall" type="text" maxlength="60" placeholder="* Номер телефона" name="formParams[phone]" value=""><br>
  <button type="submit" id="button6556653" class="button" onclick="if(window['btnprs5ee8a82e27f98']){return false;}window['btnprs5ee8a82e27f98']=true;setTimeout(function(){window['btnprs5ee8a82e27f98']=false},6000);return true;">
                                Записаться</button><br>
  <input type="hidden" id="2159905ee8a82e221a2" name="__gc__internal__form__helper" class="__gc__internal__form__helper" value="">
  <input type="hidden" id="2159905ee8a82e221a2ref" name="__gc__internal__form__helper_ref" class="__gc__internal__form__helper_ref" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="requestTime" value="1592305710">
  <input type="hidden" name="requestSimpleSign" value="6b442c8f44be7b60dc76ddf42c651c58">
  <input type="hidden" name="isHtmlWidget" value="1" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам будет достаточно добавить еще одно условие в Ваш код:

```
if (nameVal.trim().split(" ").length === 2) {
    name.css({"box-shadow": "inset 0 0 10px red"})
}
```

Методы, которые тут использованы:

[trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) - убирает возможные "whitespace" в начале и в конце значения `nameVal`;

[split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) - делит изначальную строку на отдельные строки, где (" ") означает - разделить в том месте где есть разрыв;

[length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) - возвращает длину массива, т.е количество отдельных строк.

Comment: Спасибо большое! А как можно на каждый if сделать чтобы всплывало уведомление с текстом?

Comment: Логика по отображению уведомлений располагается внутри блока `if`, т.е сейчас исходя из Вашего примера у объекта `name` изменяется CSS, а именно `box-shadow` property. Если Вы хотите делать что то другое когда данное условие срабатывает то замените третию строчку моего примера на то что Вам требуется, например `name.css("display", "block")`.